# iPhone: Best way to handle 400 UILabels in UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, graphics, uiscrollview, uilabel, lag

I've been working on a crossword app for a while. The actual game runs in a UIScrollview, because the player should be able to scroll, zoom and pan.

To the UIScrollview i added a UITapGestureRecognizer that handles the touch-event, and calculates where the player touched. So far so good.

Afterwards I added about 400 UILabels to the UIScrollview. Each of them are "empty" until the player presses a button on the keyboard. My problem is that when i add these labels the whole UIScrollview become very slow and laggy in scrolling etc.

As the user guesses the right words green tiles will become visible. The tiles are loaded in as UIImageViews. This reduces the performance again.

I have looked at DTGridView, but I've got no luck with it.

Can you please help me out and try to guide me in the right direction?

Comment: UIKit is not designed to work in scenarios like this one, you should try either Core Graphics or an OpenGL-based engine.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should implement the UIScrollview method drawRect you self instead of add 400 UILabel in it

you can set a NSArray contains 400 objects called "label";

when user pressed the button,  you should calc the postion & test of the "label" &decide which "label" should display in the scrollview in current offset .

add 400 UILabels in one UIScrollview may cause the memory problem;

Comment: Can you give me an example or direct me to some kind of tutorial? :)

Comment: i review your problem and guess that you wanna create a 20 x 20 puzzle?  so it's more easy to do ,   implement the method **drawRect** ,and draw every tile you need and decide the status of each tile ,  but i think you  should first know how to custom draw a UIView via **drawRect**

Comment: This is the approach I would use. Lots of subviews is always bad for performance, with drawRect one can draw text and graphics directly on the view.

Comment: So the drawRect method will increase the performance? :) What about the UIImageViews? Do they reduce performance too or is it only the UILabels? And how do I redraw some of the items from time to time? i want to change the text on some of the tiles etc... Can you maybe provide some sample code ? :)

Comment: I have tried to read about the drawRect, but can't figure out how to use it. If you want i can upload an image of the game, and maybe you could try to help me out so I can do it in a more efficient way and not reduce performance. Thanks for the help so far :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recycled label in your scrollview. That will improve the performance. To know how to reuse/recycle subviews in UIScrollView please check Apple WWDC videos on UIScrollView. [WWDC 2010 Sample Code](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645) . Also check UIScrollView Class Refference [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

You can get help from this link [Creating Circular and Infinite UIScrollViews](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with this for the past while/days even. Using various related answers. But eventually I used instruments and a bit of commenting to see what was slow.

I remember someone saying layoutSubviews slows things when you addSubviews, so I took my "Local" code out of there. But nothing sped up.

So when using a breakpoint during my addSubview routine, I noticed the iOS system was actually in a superview's layout calls (navigationCtrlr) during viewDidLoad.

I introduced a 0.1 second delay before adding subviews and bam! I recommend dispatch_async to prevent crashes from race conditions, but that's another subject.

In short, it might be in LayoutSubviews even if you don't think you are there.